# To save the value of flatlist in asyncstorage

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

i'm new in react native. i'm trying to save the item of flatlist. The flatlist item is Coming from autocomplete. i have diplay the autocomplete item in flatlist . i want to save the displayed item in asyncstorage.

I tried to save the data i have made one databaseHelper class.

```
<FlatList
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={this.state.timezoneArray}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={{padding:10,borderBottomWidth:1,borderBottomColor:"#000000"}}>{item}</Text>}
    />

      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.infoText}>Enter Location</Text>
      )}
```

This is my actual screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any action in auto suggestions ? How did you try to save you data ?

Comment: yes i have one json file from which i'm fetching the data and displaying all the country names.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/erdem/8c7d26765831d0f9a8c62f02782ae00d this is the link from where timezone acc to  countries coming.

Comment: You said "I tried to save the data i have made one databaseHelper class.", where are you trying to save data ? 
Incase you want to save data from the incoming countries list do update in this.setState({}) by taking a variable.

Comment: yes to save timezone i have made one databasehelper class.

Comment: this is the json file from where i have fetch the data in autocomplete. But  i made the databasehelper class for the flatlist item to save.